# isDirectory() not working for UNIX directory

Tags: java, unix

I am getting the isDirectory() value as false for the below code :-

```
public void validateFile() throws IOException {

        File dir = new File(Labels.INPUT_FILE_DIR).getCanonicalFile(); 
        // Labels.INPUT_FILE_DIR is ./Input (i.e. my Input folder in UNIX server
        String code, fileName = "";
        ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

        Logger.info(cName,mName,"");
        System.out.println("dir.isDirectory() " + dir.isDirectory()); // getting false here

        if (dir.isDirectory()) {

            for (File tempFile : dir.listFiles()) {
                System.out.println("inside the for loop ");

            }
        }

    }
```

Am i doing something wrong ?
Could anyone please help me out.

Comment: does this file exist? `isDirectory` does return `false` aswell if it doesn´t.

Comment: Since you specify `./Input`, are you sure the current directory is what you think it is? Maybe print the canonical `dir` value too.

Comment: Labels.INPUT_FILE_DIR is the path in the UNIX server like /ABC/Input

Comment: i tried printing the value of dir and it is /ABCD/Input

Comment: Are you stuck with Java 6 or less? If not, use JSR 203 instead (ie, `Files.isDirectory()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [public boolean isDirectory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory())

> `true` if and only if the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a directory; `false` otherwise

It looks like your path is not valid, can you provide full path and check if its works.

Comment: It worked with the full path :)
But why is the case its not working if i am specifying the value of Labels.INPUT_FILE_DIR as ./Input
also  File dir = new File(Labels.INPUT_FILE_DIR).getCanonicalFile(); 
the value of dir is /ABCD/Input

Comment: and what `dir` is printing?

Comment: dir :- /ABCD/Input